# How can I calculate interest portion of income when selling a stock?

Tags: stocks, interest

For religious reasons, I want to account the income from interest separately from any other income. I know that most companies today have some liquid assets, which accrue interest. But when I sell a stock how can I find what portion of my earning was from interest?

I am particularly interested in [Salesforce.com](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s=CRM%20Income%20Statement&annual)

Comment: I hypothesise that Asad Iqbal is interested in interest because of Islamic restrictions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_banking#Usury_in_Islam (and the rest of the article).

Comment: you are on spot @ChrisInEdmonton . Ideally, I shouldn't be dealing in a transaction which pays or receives interest. However, due to current economic infrastructure, scholars of fiqh allow to involve in such transactions with few conditions, one of them that the interest will be calculated and discarded.

Answer (score 1):

When you sell the stock your income is from the difference of prices between when you bought the stock and when you sold it. There's no interest there.

The interest is in two places: the underlying company assets (which you own, whether you want it or not), and in the distribution of the income to the owners (the dividends). You can calculate which portion of the interest income constitutes your dividend by allocating the portions of your dividend in the proportions of the company income. That would (very roughly and unreliably, of course) give you an estimate what portion of your dividend income derives from the interest.

Underlying assets include all the profits of the company that haven't been distributed through dividends, but rather reinvested back into the business. These may or may not be reflected in the market price of the company.

Bottom line is that there's no direct correlation between the income from the sale of the stake of ownership and the company income from interest, if any correlation at all exists.

Why would you care about interest income of Salesforce? Its not a bank or a lender, they may have some interest income, but that's definitely not the main income source of the company. If you want to know how much interest income **exactly** the company had, you'll have to dig deep inside the quarterly and annual reports, and even then I'm not sure if you'll find it as a separate item for a company that's not in the lending business.

Answer (score 1):

Their interest *expense* was $17M. Where you see $5.14/sh in Key Statistics, any daily interest received is more than canceled out by the expense paid at the same time. I understand your concern, but this company is not "sitting on cash" as are Apple, Google, etc. Short term rates are well below 1%, 1yr tbill looks like about .2%. So strictly speaking, each share might have 1 cent interest you need to concern yourself with.

Disclaimer to other readers - This has *nothing* to do with taxes. OP is asking about a specific part of the company cash flow. His worst case is $1 per 100 shares.